# I can't use variable in an if statement

Tags: java

I have no idea why this doesn't work. Please help, I am new to java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner  = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("what is your first number ");
    String firstNum = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("what is your second number ");
    String secondNum = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("what is your Third number ");
    String thirdNum = scanner.nextLine();
    if (firstNum > secondNum) {
        System.out.println("the firs number is bigger than the firs number");
```

Comment: You cannot compare String using `>` or `<` operators, there is method `compareTo` of interface `Comparable` that has to be used for this purpose: `if (firstNum.compareTo(secondNum) > 0)`

Comment: `String` is a text and your compiler is probably telling you that it has no idea what the > operator is supposed to do with Strings aka Text. If you want to read in numbers, you should really very much consider using a fitting data type like `int`, `long`, `double` etc. pp

Answer (score 1):

Scanner.nextLine() is used to input string . Instead use scanner.nextInt() to input number and store in an integer variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is an illegal comparison. You cannot compare a String to a String. You should use **Scanner.nextInt()**. If you want to use a string to store a numerical value than you can use **Integer.parseInt()** to convert string into int.